# Lorentz boosting orthogonal to the direction of a photon's momentum- what's going on here?

Tags: special-relativity, photons

So while solving a special relativity problem, the following problem came to my mind, which seems to admit two inconsistent methods of resolution. I'd like to know which is incorrect, where the mistake is, and what the most sensible way to think about this scenario is. The problem is this. Suppose an atom moving uniformly with Lorentz factor $\gamma$ with respect to our laboratory frame emits a photon orthogonal to its direction of motion. Then we know the magnitude of the photon's momentum is $p = hf/c $ where $f$ is the photon's frequency. The question is: will the frequency of the photon as observed in the laboratory frame be the same as that as observed in the atom's frame? There seem to be two approaches here, if my reasoning is correct, giving (seemingly) different answers:

1. The "obvious" approach: we know that the momentum transforms as a 4-vector, and so, since it is directed orthogonal to the axis along which we are Lorentz boosting, will be left unchanged between the two reference frames. So $f = cp/h$ is the the same in both frames.
2. We also know that for a plane wave, $(\omega/c, \vec{k})$ transforms as a 4-vector. So if we are boosting along the $x$-axis, we should have the angular frequency transform according to
   $\omega'/c = \gamma\left(\omega/c - \beta k_x\right) = \gamma\omega/c $ since $k_x = 0$ by the orthogonality condition. But this suggests that $f$ picks up a factor of $\gamma$ when we transform into the lab frame, contrary to the first method!

It seems to be that either I've committed some glaring error of reasoning, or that somehow this is an artifact of the fact that the first approach treats the photon "quantumly" and the second classically. Any insight into what's happening here would be appreciated!

Comment: “ the momentum transforms as a 4-vector, and so, since it is directed orthogonal to the axis along which we are Lorentz boosting, will be left unchanged between the two reference frames.” Hmm, why do you believe that? The y component of the 4-momentum stays the same, but that doesn’t mean all the others stay the same too.

Comment: @knzhou Because of the form of the Lorentz transforms. If we are boosting along the $x$ axis, and we choose the $y$ axis to correspond with the direction of the photon's momentum, then $p_y' = p_y$, since $(E/c,\vec{p})$ is a 4-vector. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @knzhou Ah, good point- it will pick up an $x$ component! I'll check that we get the same answer as the second method if we carry this through, but if you post this as an answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: @Art Write more. The photon momentum is orthogonal to the direction of the photons travel direction.